# Should one correct for multiple comparison for secondary outcomes in RCTs or clinical trials?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

This might a simple question answered elsewhere, but it comes up often in NHST discussions and I've heard conflicting statements. Imagine a metanalysis of 50 trials on 100,000 patients total to examine the question of whether vitamin supplementation lowers all-cause mortality, with the primary outcome being deaths in experimental (vitamin supplemented) versus control (placebo) arm. Let's say the authors also defined secondary outcomes to be cancer deaths, cardiovascular deaths, and all other types of death combined excluding cancer and cardiovascular. Now, the primary outcome does not yield at significant result at $\alpha = 0.05$. But imagine the results were significant $(p < \alpha)$ for cancer deaths and vitamin supplementation (supplementation associated with lower death rate), but not for CVD or otherwise.

My question is can the authors just arbitrarily test all of these at $\alpha = 0.05$, or should there be some correction for the fact there is multiple subgroup (I may be using this term too loosely here?) analysis? Should instead the authors use some kind of FWER correction like Bonferroni or Šidák procedure, and if so, should they treat $m=4$ (including primary outcome test) or $m=3$ (taking all secondaries together in isolation) ?